# Is $ \mathcal{F} \ : \ U \ \mapsto \ \prod_{x \in U} A_x $ a sheaf?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Here is an elementary question about sheaves to a category $\mathcal{C}$ having all its products.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{A_x \ | \ x \in X \}$ be a family of objects inside among the objects of $\mathcal{C}$. 
Now I wonder if the following assignment is a sheaf:
$$
\mathcal{F} \quad : \quad 
U \ \longmapsto \ \prod_{x \in U} A_x. 
$$
I am almost sure it is since it can also be described as
$$
\mathcal{F}' \quad : \quad 
U \ \longmapsto \ \{ U \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} Ob(\mathcal{C}) \ | \ f \text{ a map} \} \ 
$$
ans that must be a sheaf. Is this right?

Comment: Your argument is not valid. You describe $F$ as something which does not depend on the family $(A_x)$.

Comment: You should add the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ has products.

Comment: @HeinrichD, thank you for your comments! Could you explain why my argument is wrong? Is it that $\mathcal{F}'$ is no sheaf and $\mathcal{F}$ cannot be seen as $\mathcal{F}'$? According Keven Carlson, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the product over $x\in X$ of the skyscraper sheaves $A_x$, and sheaves are closed under limits.

Comment: Actually it is easier to just prove the claim directly. I don't think that someone asking such a basic question will be good with a proof using skyscraper sheaves and limits of sheaves.

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove that for every open covering  $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ and every family of morphisms $f_i : T \to \prod_{x \in U_i} A_x$ with $f_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j |_{U_i \cap U_j}$ $(\star)$ there is a unique morphism $f : T \to \prod_{x \in U} A_x$ with $f |_{U_i} = f_i$. By the universal property of products, we may define $f$ by $p_x f : T \to A_x$ for each $x \in U$. Choose some $i \in I$ with $x \in U_i$. We let $p_x f := p_x f_i$.  Because of $(\star)$ the choice of $i$ does not matter. We have $f|_{U_i}=f_i$ by construction, and it is clear that this is how we had to define $f$ in order to fulfill this equation.